# Sorting in asceding order using MS SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hello guys i want to sort data in ms SQL server in ascending order and save this change,so if i close the SQL server and reopened the same order should be. Why ??because i need  to display sorted data in html page but the easiest way is to sort using MS sql server and then display data in HTML.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using `ORDER BY` each time you query the table?

Comment: You want to select data in ascending order and save the result in another table?

Comment: each time i make order by query it's work but when i close my sql server and reopened it will get back to the default sorting which is by ID

Comment: @parkherepark That;s how SQL Server works.

Comment: ok how can i save this sorting and make it work even if i close and open my sql server ??

Comment: data in SQL Server isn't saved in any particular order.  That's why `ORDER BY` exists.

Comment: @parkherepark you can crate a clustered index with ascending order, but there is no 100% guarantee, but it works for most cases

Comment: @parkherepark, Sql Server is a service that runs continuously (and retains state across restarts if they happen). You probably mean something else when you say "close and open Sql server".

Answer (score 1):

SQL standard (so-called ANSI) does not force any default the order results are returned. Meaning, **in theory**, it could be in any order, different on each run. The intent is that if order is important, then the query must include and `order by`-clause.

In practice, `select * from X` (so without explicit order) results tend to be shown in the order they are read from DB internal storage, which quite often is a [clustered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes). If you really-really want to, you **can force DB to lay out data in the order you like be adjusting clustered index**. This may or may not be a good idea - you shouldn't do this for querying comfort-reasons, as it has strong impact on performance and should be optimized for real work, not comfort of occasional data-surfing.

I probably do not get your exact need, but "remembering" order in app is usually not done by reordering data is physical DB disk, but handled by application logic and then translated to SQL query as `ORDER BY`-clause. You app does the remembering, SQL server would do the sorting.